# Is it possible to create dynamic channels on Redis Pub/Sub?

Tags: websocket, redis, chat, scale, publish-subscribe

I am going through how to scale the Web-socket based chat applications. As part of this I am exploring distributed Redis Pub/Sub to help send the messages to the Web-sockets servers the users are connected to.

Scenario: One to one chat
When User-A wants to chat with User-B. I want to create a chat room (channel) with name "room-User-A-User-B" and then let User-A and User-B to subscribe to this channel.

Question:
Is it possible to create channels and assign subscribers dynamically in Redis Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can subscribe to the dynamic channel using the `SUBSCRIBE` command. Also, you can create a group chat where you can subscribe to more persons dynamically using the `SUBSCRIBE` command.

But there's a catch if your publisher is also subscribed on the same channel then both will get data, so for messaging app you need to create two channels "room-User-A-User-B" and "room-User-B-User-A" `B` will subscribe on channel `room-User-A-User-B` and `A` will subscribe channel `room-User-B-User-A`.

Comment: What if there is only one channel and client application handles message duplication if the user is publisher. Suppose there is from_user ID available in the message. Would it be fine?

Comment: Yes that would work fine.